# what is the best way to visualize a table on graph in r

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization

I have the following table(data frame):

```
             week24  week25 week26
 under 0.5m    1824   1878   1955
 0.5 to 1m     170    205    211
 1to3          117    109    124
 3to6           19     19     25
 6to10           9      8      8
 10to15          4      3      5
 15to30          9     13      9
 above 30m      19     32     28
```

i am looking for the best way to visualize it on a graph then i can i have row names under 0.5m:above 30m  in X axis .

i have already tried barplot() but the results are not that good

[image]

how can i make it more informative?

Comment: @akrun this is in continue of the previous questions i have used the cut points but i need a way to visualize them properly

Comment: The depends what you want to see / communicate with the plot. Would you like to compare trends between the groups? Would you like to compare the absolute size of both groups? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what exactly are you trying to obtain. Maybe just by adding the legend your graph will be way more descriptive. I've a simple data frame to show what I mean:

```
df <- data.frame(Z=c(1,2,3),Y=c(2,3,1))
row.names(df) <- c("Cat1","Cat2","Cat3")

barplot(as.matrix(df),
        legend.text = row.names(df),
        args.legend = list(x = "right"),
        col = c("blue","green","red"))
```

### [image]

If you want check better colours, check this website: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf

Comment: How can i give some color to it for different rows?